# Hide Java application from command-tab application switcher and dock in OSX

Tags: java, macos, system-tray, dock

I have a java application which has a tray icon in the top menu bar of
OSX. When I minimize the application I would like it to disappear from
the dock and the command-tab application switcher and *only* be in the
tray. I've seen other OSX applications do this, so I do believe it is
possible, but as a newbie to OSX I have no idea how to achieve it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758083/how-do-i-put-a-java-app-in-the-system-tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758083/how-do-i-put-a-java-app-in-the-system-tray)

Comment: I believe this doesn't quite asnwer my question, unfortunately. I already am able to put the application in the "system tray", what I'd like to do further is to make the application disappear from the dock at the bottom of the screen, and the command-tab application switcher

Comment: I really need an answer to this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, SWT 3.5 had a bug which prevented it from properly reacting to the Info.plist that OSX requires to hide the application. This bug is fixed in SWT 3.6, and with Eclipse Helios being released today, I believe SWT is now officially at version 3.6

To achieve the hidden icon, at the top of your info.plist file you simply need to add the following line:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: or use Property List Editor to add the LSUIElement key