# SWT on OSX: Windows open under other applications

Tags: java, macos, swt

I'm having trouble with my SWT application where the shells/dialogs always open underneath other windows by default ("pop-under"). if I set the SWT.ON_TOP bit, the window opens properly on top, but then I block other applications, which isn't really desirable either...

I'm wondering if there's a proper way to specify that I want the window to pop-up, rather then underneath other applications.

Thanks!

Comment: I should also mention that the window opens underneath AND out of focus...

Comment: additionally, this problem appears to be related to LSUIElement being set to 1 in Info.plist, so the application runs as an "agent"

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995625/hide-java-application-from-command-tab-application-switcher-and-dock-in-osx). What's your SWT version? It should be resolved in the latest version, as is explained there. Also see [this bug report at Eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=268687).