# How to Hide a Java App from Alt+Tab?

Tags: java

I have used Java to write a program to show some message on the screen on top of every other window. When I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I don't want to see it. How can I hide it from <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>? The OS is windows 7

Comment: If this is an OS X question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995625/hide-java-application-from-command-tab-application-switcher-and-dock-in-osx

Comment: Discussion about the Windows side of things (not Java-specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357076/best-way-to-hide-a-window-from-the-alt-tab-program-switcher