# How to add application to System Tray

Tags: java, swing, icons, awt, system-tray

I want to add my application to the system tray when it's window is closed (similar to the Google Talk application). And then when I click the on icon in the system tray the application window becomes active again. How can I do this in Java?

```
final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images.jpg");
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
try {
   SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
} catch (AWTException e2) {
   e2.printStackTrace();
}

this.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
   public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
      if (e.getNewState() == EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {

         trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               setVisible(true);
            }
         });
         setVisible(false);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I put a Java app in the system tray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758083/how-do-i-put-a-java-app-in-the-system-tray)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have set `DefaultCloseOperations` correctly

```
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE)
```

this code line is same as `myFrame.setVisible(false)`, then for restore of `JFrame` from `JPopupMenu` to call only `myFrame.setVisible(true)`

Comment: thanks for this. but i am not using Popup to restore. i want when i click on icon in system tray it should open my Login window.

Comment: then add [MouseListener to the Icon in the SystemTray](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460383/714968)

Answer (score 2):

I got answer. Now when i close window its closing and when i click on System tray icon then it again open my window

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/ChatIcon1.jpeg");
    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
    trayIcon.setToolTip("OfficeCommunicator");
    try {
        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }


                trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        trayIcon.displayMessage("hi", "You Opened Me Again", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                        setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
}
```