# JavaFX 2.0 Window to Tray

Tags: java, windows, javafx-2

I want to develop a service with JavaFX UI (all-in-one). When the user clicks on the Close button I want to move the app to the system tray and keep it opened with all the listeners active.

For now, what I achieved is that when someone clicks on close button the app gets minimized.

Anyone knows how to move the app to the tray (At least in windows systems)?

Thanks

Comment: Have there been any new developments on this?

Comment: @ClickUpvote Asked as recently as August 2012: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17503 => *"It is targeted for Lombard. There's no concrete ETA yet."*

Comment: @assylias login required, I can't log in to that site.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Regitration is free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2311451). In summary:

- at present, the easiest solution seems to be to embed your application in AWT and [use AWT to place your application to the system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758083/how-do-i-put-a-java-app-in-the-system-tray)
- the feature is targeted in JavaFX 3.0, i.e. 2013 according to [the current roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html)
- the OP in that discussion uses a circumvoluted method that I have not tested but might do what you need.

Comment: Waw... There is no way in JavaFX 2.0? Thanks for your answer!