# Java Program and Windows Taskbar

Tags: java

I just wrote a desktop clock for me in java-swing and I wanted that clock to run everytime I log in.
For this I added the my jar file to start folder and I got the clock running.
But my problem is- the icon shown in the taskbar that allows me to close my application by clicking the cross mark shown at mouse over (Windows 7 style) or right click->close.
I want my application to run as the other windows processes (or desktop gadgets) and not to show the icon in the taskbar.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a JDialog instead of JFrame. Dialogs do not show in the task bar.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might be  interested in something like this

 Put this code where you are creating the form

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

This disables any action on close.

Comment: Thanks Anirudhvarma ! Actually I wanted no icons to be displayed in taskbar which I got by Durandal's answer however your answer was also very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do the decoration of the window yourself.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean)

See also : [How do I put a Java app in the system tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758083/how-do-i-put-a-java-app-in-the-system-tray)

Comment: Hi Aubin ! I am talking about the icon in the windows taskbar and not the title bar of my application(I already have setUndecorated as true). And also I don't want any icon to be placed in taskbar tray as well(your second link).

Comment: anirudhvarma gives the answer you expect, I think.