# How to send java application to system tray?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, system-tray

can anybody help me to send java application to system tray?I tried some ways but i totally failed.i want to send my application to system tray once it is opened because application should run in the background without seen the interface.

Comment: this question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758083/how-do-i-put-a-java-app-in-the-system-tray

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [java.awt.SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) class.

(You should search in google first: [java system tray](https://www.google.com.tw/#q=java+system+tray). The first link is The Java<sup>TM</sup> Tutorail: [How to Use the System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html))